# View Table Values in dropdown list Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam new to codeIgniter; my problem is I have database with table `cartegories_meta_data`

```
meta_cartegory_id | meta_cartegory_name 
------------------|--------------------
 395              |  Soft Drinks 
 11111            |  Hot Drinks
```

I have a model Add_items

```
public function getcartegory()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `cartegories_meta_data`");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller items

```
public function additems()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Add_items');
    $data['result'] = $this->Add_items->getcartegory();
    $this->load->view('menu');
    $this->load->view('additems', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer1');
}
```

And on my view I load array result in for each loop

```
<?php 
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row->meta_cartegory_id;
        $name = $row->meta_cartegory_name;
    } 
?>
```

Now what I want is to create a drop down list... which will show all cartegory names and their id as value

```
<?php 
    $options = array($id => $name );
    $more =' class ="form-control"';
    echo form_dropdown('item_cartegory', $options, 11111, $more); 
?>
```

The current code give me

```
<option value="11111" selected="selected">Hot Drinks</option>
```

But what I want  is to get something like this

```
<option value="395">Soft Drinks</option>
<option value="11111" selected="selected">Hot Drinks</option>
```

Can you help me on how i can deal with the for each loop to get what i want or is there another way

Comment: Non-programming error: it's "category" not "cartegory"

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that it's because there is another table called category_meta_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the option inside loop like this.

```
<select>

<?php
  $flag=0;
  foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

  if(flag==0)
  {
     //code to select the first item
       <option value="<?php echo $row->meta_cartegory_id; selected="selected"?>" ><?php echo $row->meta_cartegory_name; ?></option>
   flag=1;
   }
   else
   {
     //remove the selected here
       <option value="<?php echo $row->meta_cartegory_id;?>" ><?php echo $row->meta_cartegory_name; ?></option>
    }
  } ?>

</select>
```

Let me know if there is an error

Comment: Thanks for reply... that code works , but what if the data in table categories_meta_data are more than 2 rows ( meaning these data are added frequently and I can not predict how many they will be) so I need a loop which will loop and show all values automatically

Comment: this code can output one or more rows because it is in loop. What's  your current problem now?